# Is it possible to use a proxy with LinqToTwitter library?

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I want to know if it is possible to use a proxy to connect twitter with `LinqToTwitter` (c#) library. The objetive is to hide the ip source.

Answer (score 3):

I just browsed through the `LinqToTwitter` library [source code here](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/95a7d0811720#LinqToTwitterAg/LinqToTwitter/TwitterExecute.cs) and even though I didn't find a way to specify a Proxy, the library uses HttpWebRequest internally, which will use a Proxy if you specify it in the App.config file as so:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true">
   <proxy bypassonlocal="true"
          proxyaddress="http://proxy.domain.org:8888/" />
  </defaultProxy>
 </system.net>
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx) has this regarding the Proxy property in HttpWebRequest:

> The Proxy property identifies the WebProxy object to use to process
>   requests to Internet resources. To specify that no proxy should be
>   used, set the Proxy property to the proxy instance returned by the
>   GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy method. The local computer or
>   application config file may specify that a default proxy be used. If
>   the Proxy property is specified, then the proxy settings from the
>   Proxy property override the local computer or application config file
>   and the HttpWebRequest instance will use the proxy settings specified.
>   If no proxy is specified in a config file and the Proxy property is
>   unspecified, the HttpWebRequest class uses the proxy settings
>   inherited from Internet Explorer on the local computer. If there are
>   no proxy settings in Internet Explorer, the request is sent directly
>   to the server. The HttpWebRequest class parses a proxy bypass list
>   with wildcard characters inherited from Internet Explorer the same as
>   the bypass list is parsed directly by Internet Explorer. For example,
>   the HttpWebRequest class will parse a bypass list of "nt*" from
>   Internet Explorer as a regular expression of "nt.*". So a URL of
>   "http://nt.com" would bypass the proxy using the HttpWebRequest class
>   and using Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thank you, i will try to use this and next, to try to use it changing dynamically.